# Error Hibernate Could not autowire

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ember.js, intellij-idea

I have a project in Intellij using Spring and Hibernate. Also I'm using Ember for connecting with the backend. When I run the program I get the error:

```
 19:06:07.081 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ro.ubbcluj.exam.core.service.AuthorService ro.ubbcluj.exam.web.controller.AuthorController.authorService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ro.ubbcluj.exam.core.service.AuthorService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: { @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
```

and other ones but this is the first and I think the main problem.

The author controller class:

```
@RestController
public class AuthorController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorService authorService; // a red error here saying Could not autowire

    @Autowired
    private AuthorConverter authorConverter;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authors", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.API_JSON)
    public AuthorsDataDto getAuthors() {
        List<Author> authors = authorService.findAll();

        Set<AuthorDto> authorsDtos = authorConverter.convertModelsToDtos(authors);

        AuthorsDataDto result = new AuthorsDataDto(authorsDtos);

        return result;

    }
}
```

Has some had this error?

EDIT:

my main pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ro.ubbcluj.exam</groupId>
<artifactId>exam</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>exam-core</module>
    <module>exam-web</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.7.1.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <org.springframework.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
    <spring-test-dbunit.version>1.1.0</spring-test-dbunit.version>

    <!-- DB -->
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <HikariCP-java6.version>2.2.5</HikariCP-java6.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.182</h2.version>

    <!-- Web -->
    <javax.servlet-api.version>3.0.1</javax.servlet-api.version>

    <!-- Parsers -->
    <jackson.version>2.3.3</jackson.version>

    <!-- Apache Commons -->
    <commons-lang.version>3.3.2</commons-lang.version>

    <!-- Utilities -->
    <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.8</lombok.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>2.5</log4j.version>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
    <hamcrest-all.version>1.3</hamcrest-all.version>
    <dbunit.version>2.5.2</dbunit.version>

</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- ====== -->
        <!-- Spring -->
        <!-- ====== -->
        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-test-dbunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DATABASE & TRANSACTION MANAGER RELATED -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
            <version>${HikariCP-java6.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- H2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Parsers -->
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ============== -->
        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <!-- ============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ========= -->
        <!-- Utilities -->
        <!-- ========= -->
        <!-- GUAVA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ======= -->
        <!-- Logging -->
        <!-- ======= -->
        <!-- SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Log4j 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ======= -->
        <!-- Testing -->
        <!-- ======= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest-all.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- ====== -->
    <!-- Spring -->
    <!-- ====== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Parsers -->
    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <!-- ============== -->
    <!-- Apache Commons -->
    <!-- ============== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOMBOK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ======= -->
    <!-- Logging -->
    <!-- ======= -->
    <!-- SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Log4j 2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ======= -->
    <!-- Testing -->
    <!-- ======= -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I said my main pom.xml because I have two child folders and each of them has another pom.xml.

EDIT2:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>AuthorsAndBooksApp</display-name>

  <!--<session-config>-->
  <!--<session-timeout>1</session-timeout>-->
  <!--</session-config>-->

  <!-- Spring root -->
  <context-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>
     org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
 </param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>ro.ubbcluj.exam.web.config</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
<param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
<param-value>local</param-value>
</context-param>

 <listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name> //rest is red underlined
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name> // here rest is red!!!!!!!
<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
```

```
<!-- <welcome-file-list> -->
<!-- <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> -->
<!-- </welcome-file-list> -->

</web-app>
```

Comment: could you share your spring configuration?

Comment: The file that you have shared is maven configuration, not spring configuration. Spring configuration file will have bean declarations.

Comment: Sorry, now I think is alright

Comment: No, it should be a java class with `@Configuration` annotation at the top the class.

Comment: Of, I don't know but I resolve it. I had some unmapped thinks in Spring application context. Thank you for your patience